# How to Interpolate in Parent by passing locals to Child in PUG

Tags: templates, inheritance, pug, interpolation

Is there a way to update locals for parent and then use it in child via extends?  I have a question regarding the basic example shown on PUG website.  See screenshot.[image]

```
//- layout.pug
html
  head
    title My Site - #{title}
    block scripts
      script(src='/jquery.js')
  body
    block content
    block foot
      #footer
        p some footer content

//- page-a.pug
extends layout.pug

block scripts
  script(src='/jquery.js')
  script(src='/pets.js')

block content
  h1= title
  - var pets = ['cat', 'dog']
  each petName in pets
    include pet.pug
```

If I am using express, I wish to update the #{title} in layout.pug and pass it to page-a.pug.  Is the following syntax correct?

```
res.render('page-a',{title:'Some Title'})  //Will this update head title in layout.pug as well?
```

Comment: Please edit your question to not rely on text within an image

Comment: The text I have provided describes the question on its own.   Image is for reference to PUG documentation only.  Do you by any chance know the answer to the question?

Comment: There's some text in the image that isn't in the question. Have you tried the syntax you've described at the end? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Passing locals to page-a.pug will also update the local of parent (layout.pug). Just wrote some test code to confirm.

```
//- pet.pug
p= petName


// app.js 
const PORTNUM = 4000

const express = require('express'); 
 
const app = express(); 

app.set('view engine', 'pug'); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.render('page-a',{title:'Some Title'})  //This will update the head title in layout.pug as well); 
}); 

app.listen(PORTNUM, () => { 
    console.log(`The application is running on localhost:${PORTNUM}!`) 
});
```